# How does this button work without any circuit closing device?

Tags: pcb, diodes, button

This may be a stupid question, but I have searched online for a little bit and can't seem to find my answer. I am working on a circuit board that uses buttons that i've never seen before. These buttons just have a metal lead around them and an LED in the middle (for lighting up the button I'd assume) but how does a button like this even work? I've attached some pictures to show you what i mean. 
[image]

this is the back of the push buttons from the device

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gold plated interlocking concentric "rings" are two contacts of a switch.
When they are electrically connected by a resistance of less than say 10 k Ohms the circuit is activated.

The white "rubber" has a conductive ring on it which is close to but not touching the gold contacts - it is probably held clear by small protrusions in the rubber moudling. When the rubber is pressed from above it presses the ring onto both contacts and closes the circuit.

The conductive material is often made of a conductive ink or similar which may be loaded with carbon particles to make it conductive.

Comment: so this is probably pretty hard to replicate on my own circuits huh?

Thank you for the explanation though, i thought that might be it, but i wasn't too sure because that black ring is rubber, but your explanation clears up any doubt.

Comment: @nfoggia: It's easy enough to replicate; all you need on the PCB is a pattern, and there are a few sources for premade buttons.

Comment: what would you even call one of these buttons?

Comment: @nfoggia: They're usually called "silicone" or "impregnated rubber" buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The black ring on the bottom of the rubbery buttons is conductive, and it allows current to flow between the interleaved petals of the PCB pattern when the button is pressed.

Comment: Agh - answer overlap :-). I should post the 1st para then complete the answer in such cases to show I'm here. No matter.